# Can I retrieve the worksheet order from an Excel workbook in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an SSIS package that loads the data from multiple worksheets in an excel workbook into a SQL Server table, appends additional data from other SQL Server tables by means of an update to the table and then exports it out to another spreadsheet containing the same worksheets with the same names as the original load spreadsheet.

On the original load I am retrieving the worksheet names using a ado.net schema connection pulling in the details from the Table schema of the excel workbook. iterating through each sheet and pulling the data into the table appending the sheet name to each row.

This all works fine. The issue I am having is when exporting the data back out to excel. I can force an order but I don't know what order the worksheets were in in the original file.

I have tried creating an incremental ID number when loading the sheets but, it does not load them in the order they are displayed. I have also looked through the schemas available and can't see any that give the sheet order, however, I have looked at the xml files that make up the Excel document and found what appears to be an r:ID in the `Workbook.xml` file under the sheets tag which appears to be in the order the sheets are displayed.

Is there a way of retrieving this information when loading the spreadsheet into the SQL Server table.

Comment: Maybe change your logic a little bit. Maybe use the source Excel workbook also as the target - copy it under new name, then clear all sheets. This way you'll have order of sheets preserved.

Comment: @Endrju thank you for this suggestion, I have been working through this trying to get it working and I have it working to a point. I have been able to copy and clear the spreadsheet and repopulate it with the new data, however, when it writes the new data back to the sheet it adds it after the end of where the previous data was written. i.e. if the sheet had 100 rows of data previously when I write the new data to the sheet it starts writing at row 101. Is this something in the way I am clearing the data, i am using Drop Table in a Execute SQL Command.

Comment: Longy I've never went so deep into this, however your approach should be working. I found an interesting blog post, maybe google a bit more and you'll find the answer... https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/